# Map is not visible in Kibana (4.1.3)

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, kibana, apache-flink, kibana-4

I used [this example](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-streaming-demo) in order to create a simple Kibana dashboard with a streaming data. So, the example runs a Flink program to simulate a streaming data flow and to save it into Elasticsearch in real time (version 1.7.3). The dashboard is created in Kibana 4.1.3.

The problem is that the map is not visible in Kibana dashboard. See this screenshot.

[image]

I followed Readme step by step, but for some reason the example `SlidingArravalCount.scala` is not working properly. Also, since this is a streaming data (simulated), I expected to see a dynamically updated map in which the colors of rectangles are changing in real-time, but I see a static image all the time. To see updates, I should click on Refresh button. Is it possible to setup an automatic refresh in Kibana 4.1.3?

Also, my visualization `Map` is not shown in a Dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know what zoom level you're in?

Comment: @Val: I cannot see the map independently on a zoom level. I tried to zoom in and zoom out until limits, but still, the map does not appear.

Comment: What does your developer console say? Any JS errors or anything else?

Comment: @Val: I finally switched to Kibana 5.0.1 and this problem was solved.